How can I invert a transformation matrix made by two concatenated matrices?
If I have two transformation matrices A and B, I can concatenate them and apply the resulting matrix to a matrix X in order to obtain matrix Y: $Y=(A|B) \cdot X$.
Can I turn back to obtain X, given A, B and Y in the following way $X=(A^{-1}|B^{-1}) \cdot Y$ ?
In other words: is $(A^{-1}|B^{-1}) = (A|B)^{-1}$ ?

apparently concatenate means put side by side.  As to your last line, if $A,B$  are square matrices, the concatenate is not,  it cannot have an inverse

Meanwhile, for the Kronecker product, $A^{-1} \otimes  B^{-1}  $ really is the inverse of $A \otimes B$

https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prodotto_di_Kronecker  or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product

thanks @WillJagy
